How to add geometry nodes using Python
Help please. I want to add geometry nodes using Python.
I assume/guess the steps are

Create a primitive
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add()


Add a new geometry node
bpy.ops.node.new_geometry_nodes_modifier()


Add the node I want
from_node = bpy.ops.node.add_node(use_transform=True, type="GeometryNodeCurveArc")


Connect the new node to the output
to_node = nodes["Group Output"]


links.new(from_node.outputs["Curve"], to_node.inputs["Geometry"])


Start using the node


Needless to say, this does not work. What, please, is the correct code?
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.node.add_node.poll() failed, context is incorrect


Do it without context operations (bpy.ops. [...]). See this q.

@Leander
Please will you tell me what I should use instead of:
bpy.ops.node.new_geometry_nodes_modifier()
I just don't get it. I have tried.

Use the bmesh module to create a plane primitive. Output the bmesh into a new mesh data block, then create a new object with that mesh.
import bpy
import bmesh

me = bpy.data.meshes.new("mesh name")
ob = bpy.data.objects.new("object name", me)
bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(ob)

bm = bmesh.new()
bmesh.ops.create_grid(bm, x_segments=1, y_segments=1, size=1)
bm.to_mesh(me)

Add a new modifier and create the nodes in the node group.
Check out this answer about group interface.
mod = ob.modifiers.new("Geo Node Modifier", type='NODES')
node_group = bpy.data.node_groups.new("group name", type='GeometryNodeTree')
node_group.interface.new_socket(name="Geo In", in_out ="INPUT", socket_type="NodeSocketGeometry")
node_group.interface.new_socket(name="Geo Out", in_out ="OUTPUT", socket_type="NodeSocketGeometry")

node_in        = node_group.nodes.new("NodeGroupInput")
node_transform = node_group.nodes.new("GeometryNodeTransform")
node_out       = node_group.nodes.new("NodeGroupOutput")

node_group.links.new(node_in.outputs[0], node_transform.inputs[0])
node_group.links.new(node_transform.outputs[0], node_out.inputs[0])

node_transform.inputs["Translation"].default_value[2] = 1

mod.node_group = node_group

